# Array as Parameter from Rails Select Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a legacy project that is using `acts_as_taggable_on` which expects tags to come in arrays. I have a select box allowing users to select a tag on a Course in a field called categories. The only way mass assignment create will work is if params looks like this `params = {:course => {:categories => ['Presentation']}}`. I've currently a view with this helper:

```
 <%= f.select 'categories', ['Presentation' , 'Round Table' , 'Demo', 'Hands-on'] %>
```

Which will give me a parameter like `params = {:course => {:categories => 'Presentation'}}`. This doesn't work since Acts as tag gable apparently can't handle being passed anything other than a collection.

I've tried changing `categories` to `categories[]` but then I get this error:

```
undefined method `categories[]' for #<Course:0x007f9d95c5b810>
```

Does anyone know the ***correct*** way to format my select tag to return an array to the controller? I'm using Rails 3.2.3

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work with acts_as_taggable_on, but maybe this simple hack will be suitable for you? You should put it before mass-assignment.

```
category = params[:course][:categories]
params[:course][:categories] = [category]
```

Comment: that works, but it's not what i'm looking for, rails should support passing select parameters via an array

Answer (score 0):

If you are only going to allow the selection of ONE tag, you could do:

```
<%= f.select 'categories', [['Presentation'] , ['Round Table'] , ['Demo'], ['Hands-on']] %>
```

Each one item array will have first for the display value,  and last for the return value,  which in this case will both return the same thing,  as the first element of the array is the same as the last element when the array as one element.

Comment: That syntax doesn't work, rails just pulls out the string in the array. So `['Presentation']` just goes to `'Presentation'`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like select doesn't give you that option.

If I understand correctly, one option might be to use a select_tag instead and just be explicit about where you want the selection in the params:

```
<%= select_tag 'course[categories][]', options_for_select(['Presentation' , 'Round Table' , 'Demo', 'Hands-on']) %>
```

That ought to get your params the way you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm using for one of my projects:

```
<% options = { include_blank: true } %>

<% html_options = { required: true, name: "#{f.object_name}[#{resource.id}][days][]" } %>

<%= f.select :days, DAYS, options, html_options %>
```

Without `html_options[:name]`, Rails handles the name of the select tag and spits out something like

```
service[service_add_ons_attributes][11][days]
```

but I need

```
service[service_add_ons_attributes][11][days][]
```

So I override it.

Hope that helps.